# Riemann tensor and Bianchi identities

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors

I'm trying to grab some Riemannian geometry through "The geometry of Kerr black holes". After a few computations, I managed to derive the Bianchi curvature identities from the definition of the Riemann tensor and its cyclic symmetry.

This leads me to ask the following questions:

1) as the properties of the covariant derivative seem to play no role in this derivation, does it mean that the Bianchi identities hold for every tensor of type $(1,3)$ having the symmetries of the Riemann tensor?

2) is the Riemann tensor determined up to a multiplicative constant by its group of symmetries?

Comment: What do you mean by (2)? More precisely, what do you mean by the group of symmetries of a tensor? There are several ways to interpret these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, but good luck finding another interesting example of such a tensor.

2) Not in $4$ or more dimensions. (For $2$ or $3$, see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/77973/riemann-tensor-in-2d-and-3d).)